# How to use BETWEEN date and time mysql if date and time with different field in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table `reservasi` with structure data like this:

- `id_reservasi`
- `package_name`      <- varchar
- `date_check_in`     <- varchar format (d-m-Y)
- `time_check_in`     <- varchar format (h:i:s)
- `price`             <- varchar

I want select data with filter between from date and time from previous data `reservasi` to Until the time specified.

For now, I use this sql query:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total
FROM reservasi 
WHERE date(str_to_date(date_check_in,'%d-%m-%Y')) BETWEEN date(str_to_date('$date_check_in_rekap','%d-%m-%Y')) AND date(str_to_date('$date_now','%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(time_check_in, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$time_check_in_rekap', '%H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('$time_now', '%H:%i:%s')
```

But it don't show any data...
How to use `BETWEEN` correctly?

Comment: thanks for edited @vkp

Comment: BTW, you're vulnerable to **SQL Injection**, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php to learn how to secure yourself

Comment: i am using pdo to CRUD sir...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for query from @Blag

Work Perfect...

Edited Mysql Query :

`SELECT SUM(price) AS total
FROM t 
WHERE str_to_date(CONCAT(date_check_in,' ',time_check_in) ,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
BETWEEN str_to_date('$date_check_in_previous $time_check_in_previous') AND now()`

Comment: Don't use this, SQL injection vulnerable : https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

edit, PDO version :

```
$cek_pembelian=$this->pdo->prepare("
    SELECT 
        SUM(netto_bersih) AS netto_beli, 
        SUM(jumlah_dibayar) AS rupiah_beli 
    FROM p_penerimaan_tbs 
    WHERE str_to_date(CONCAT(tanggal,' ',jam_keluar) ,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') 
        BETWEEN str_to_date(:datetime_start ,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AND now()
        ");
$cek_pembelian->execute(array(
    ':datetime_start'=>$tanggal_rekap .' '. $jam_rekap
    ));
```

---

This is what you want I think ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36ed5c/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total
FROM t 
WHERE str_to_date(CONCAT(date_check_in,' ',time_check_in) ,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
BETWEEN '2017-01-24 18:20:33' AND now()
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36ed5c/3/0)**:

```
| total |
|-------|
|   300 |
```

Comment: Thanks for answer... i am try query like this... 
`$cek_pembelian=$this->pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(netto_bersih) AS netto_beli, SUM(jumlah_dibayar) AS rupiah_beli FROM p_penerimaan_tbs WHERE str_to_date(CONCAT(tanggal,' ',jam_keluar) ,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '$tanggal_rekap $jam_rekap' AND now()");` 

Result sum total row... not filter

Comment: @DammahSifLa take a look at the edit. your problem is how you wrote your date. the MySQL way is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` so anything than that should be manually parsed with `str_to_date()`. BTW, I secured your query by not putting the php `$var` inside the SQL, but use a `:flag` instead and providing in the `execute()` the array of `:flag => $value` that PDO should use